# Different Views for Search Results in Dynamics 365 CRM Unified Interface

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I have two instances of Dynamics 365 CRM (Unified Interface). In **Instance 1**, When searching for some data it uses the **Quick Find View** in the entity itself. But in **Instance 2** it uses some unknown **Search Results View** and fetches data from all the Views.

***Note: Both the Instances are of same version.***

How is it taking this **Search Results View** and where can I find it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a new feature in 2020 release wave 1 - search happens in current in view rather than across the entity via Quick find.

> Searching for records on a grid is more intuitive with the current view definition honored when performing search. The Search this view capability on the grid now applies the current view conditions and then searches on the fields that are configured in the quick find view definition. Enabled by default, administrators can switch back to quick find search experience easily, which targets an entity's quick find view definition for searching against and for displaying results.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2020wave1/microsoft-powerapps/improvements-quick-find-search-experience-grid)

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can we switch back to Quick Find View?

Comment: @RonakLodaya did you try in system settings/preview area? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/user/grid-filters